# Toggle CSS class KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js

I have month links

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: factMonthes">
    <li data-bind="click: $root.changeFactMonth, css:{'selected-month': num == $root.activeFactMonth()}">
</ul>
```

I want to disable class "selected-month" for all links, except active and enable to active after click. Of course, i can disable class in my method changeFactMonth(), but can i do it with knockout bindings?

```
function FactMonth(num){
    this.num = num;
    this.name = MonthesNames[num - 1];
    this.active = false;
}

function ViewModel() {

    self.factMonthes = ko.observableArray();       
    self.activeFactMonth = ko.observable(new Date().getMonth() + 1);

    for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        var month = new FactMonth(i);
        month.active = self.activeFactMonth() == i;
        self.factMonthes.push(month);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `)` in your binding text: `activeFactMonth())`

Comment: it is not real code, syntax error is not important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `month_num` is an observable then you need to unwrap it:

```
<li data-bind="
  click: $root.changeFactMonth, 
  css:{'selected-month': month_num() == $root.activeFactMonth()}
">
```

You can use observables directly only when you do not use them as part of an expression. Since the comparison (`==`) is an expression, you must use the underlying values, i.e. you must call the observable.

Comment: No, num of the month is not observable. Object Factmonth is observable. Look my post's update please.

Comment: @Ozerich Just make the `FactMonth`'s `active` property an observable (`this.active = ko.observable(false);`). Bind your css to that observable (`data-bind="css: {'selected-month': active }"`). Done. Of course, don't forget to modify `changeFactMonth()` so that it does not do `month.active = true;`, but `month.active(true);`

Comment: Yes, it is right. Css enables when month active, but CSS class doesnt delete after set property to false;